# Android support libraries - exact same vs mixed versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio I am dealing with the following warning message:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-rc02, 27.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.0

[image]

So I thought to have it fixed, I need to add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compact:28.0.0-rc02'
```

But there is no such version available. I tried even `28.0.0`.

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-media-compact:28.0.0

What am I doing wrong and what are my options here? Downgrade to `27.0.0`?

I hope not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02'
```

There is only one `c` in `compat`.

Comment: @Ωmega: Trust me, I've made worse ones. :-)